# Possible to guess RSA public key $e$ using $n$ and $\phi$

Tags: rsa, public-key

We know that if $n$ and $\phi$ is known, then it is possible to find $p$ and $q$ (initial prime numbers). I have following the questions:

1. Assume the public key $e$ is not known, how difficult would it be to guess the public key using $n$, $\phi$, $p$ and $q$?
2. Assuming we have $c_1$, $c_1 = m^e \bmod n$ is it possible to find out $m$ without knowing $e$ and $d$ ?
3. From my point of view $ed = K*\phi(n) + 1$ it is difficult to guess $e$ and $d$ product. Will it fall into the factorization problem ? Is this the only equation with $n$ and $\phi$ that involves $e$ and $d$ ?
4. Can we use some algorithm for guessing $e$ and $d$ ?

I know $e$ needs to be published publicly but if $e$ is lost how can it be identified?

Comment: Is this about textbook RSA or a practical variation?

Comment: Sarien, Trying to evaluate RSA in detail and thinking about different scenarios for practical implementation. Searching a public key from the pool of public keys is what leading me to this thought. Any Suggestions ?

Comment: Public exponents are in most cases either 3 or 65537.

Comment: Is there any definite solution ? Event if we apply brute force to find M finding M using n, phi and C1 is possible ?

Comment: As I said, try first e=3 and e=65537. You will get in most cases the correct exponent. If that doesn't work, you can brute-force all small prime values e which are coprime to p-1 and q-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Assume the public key $e$ is not known, how difficult would it be to
>   guess the public key using $n$, $\phi$, $p$ and $q$?

$e$ can be chosen completely arbitrary and independently of the modulus and related variables ($\phi,p,q$). You can't learn anything about $e$ (assuming $d$ isn't given) only with the modulus given.

> Assuming we have $c_1$, $c_1 = m^e \bmod n$ is it possible to find out
>   $m$ without knowing $e$ and $d$ ?

To recover $m$ you *need* to know $d$ (by the RSA assumption), so there's no way to recover $m$ without $e$ or $d$.

> From my point of view $ed = K*\phi(n) + 1$ it is difficult to guess
>   $e$ and $d$ product. Will it fall into the factorization problem ?

You can arbitrarily choose either $e$ or $d$. The other one is a direct result of the above equation. You can't learn the $K$ either (how would you?) so even the ability to factor won't help you. Even if you'd know $K$ factoring the product would still be quite infeasible as this would be of the same size as the modulus, for which factoring is considered infeasible.

> Is this the only equation with $n$ and $\phi$ that involves $e$ and $d$ ?

Yes, this is the only RSA related equation involving, or rather this is the only equation: $ed\equiv1\pmod\phi$.

> Can we use some algorithm for guessing $e$ and $d$ ?

If you're lucky, you can indeed. $e$ usually takes the values $3,17,65537$ and if those don't yield the correct messages, you can still try each possible (small) $e$ value until you hit a good one. If $e$ is larger than $\approx 2^{40}$ you'll have a hard time finding this value.

Comment: One must not try every value e, because e must be coprime to $\phi$.

Comment: @Cryptostasis, well, if $e$ isn't coprime then verification will fail in an early state and then you wouldn't save *too* much. And BTW, I think you meant "one doesn't have to try every value e,..." because in english "must not" means something like "never ever do this!".

Comment: Thank you for the language hint. That is not meant ironically. I am not a native speaker(as you surely noticed) and I  really appreciate any hint to improve my language skills.

Answer (score 0):

For the problem of determining the base ($m$), the problem is that you don't have enough information.  For any valid value of $e$, there is a matching value $m$ that encrypts to the same $c$; specifically, $m = c^d \mod n$.  Because there are many, many possible answers, there's no way to determine this, *unless* the value of $e$ is very small or predictable, as noted in other answers.  You would still need a way to know whether your guess of $e$ is correct, such as an expected form of $m$.

Also consider the related problem of where you know $m$ but want to find $e$ and/or $d$.  This degenerates to the discrete logarithm problem over primes $p$ and $q$.  The ciphertext $c$ can be split into $p$ and $q$ "halves" as $c_p = c \mod p$ and $c_q = c \mod q$.  $m$ can be split into $m_p$ and $m_q$ the same way.  ($e$ and $d$ are conceptually split modulo $p-1$ and $q-1$.) Now, you'd need to calculate $e_p$ for $c_p = {m_p}^{e_p} \mod p$, which is the discrete logarithm problem.  Depending upon the choice and size of $p$ and $q$, this may be infeasible.

I'm not a mathematician or cryptographer, just a programmer, so treat my answer with some skepticism.